# H1 won't use all available space even though both it and its container have a much bigger width (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css

I have a H1 that is placed inside a .container div with a width of 800px. I tried giving the H1 a width also and that didn't fix it either. I can't think of any reason why this H1 wouldn't take the full width (taking it out of the .container div makes it work). Any idea what's causing this?

*Thanks in advance.*

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container" id="header-block">
        <h2>Cristian M.</h2>
        <h3>Product Designer</h3>
        <p>Hi, I'm Cristian Moisei and I'm currently a Product Designer at <a id="screencloud-link" href="https://www.screen.cloud">ScreenCloud</a>. I formerly worked as the Lead Product Designer for <a id="glofox-link" href="https://www.glofox.com">Glofox</a> and ran a design studio, <a id="hyperion-link" href="http://www.hyperion.co">Hyperion</a>, for 4 years.</p>

        <div id="extra-info">
            <p>
                <a href="#">Resume</a> <span id="slash">&#160&#160&#160/&#160&#160&#160</span>
                <a href="#">My Process</a> <span id="slash">&#160&#160&#160/&#160&#160&#160</span> 
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </p>
            <p>I live in London, UK</p>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="glofox-block">
        <div class="container">
            <img src="Images/macbook.png">
            <div id="text">
                <h1 id="number">01.</h1>
                <h1>Reinventing Glofox's interface for a complex user base.</h1>
                <div id="view-project">
                    <a href="#">View Project</a>
                    <img src="Images/arrow-white.png">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="webfaction-block">
            <div class="container">
                <div id="text">
                    <h1 id="number">02.</h1>
                    <h1>Helping Webfaction attract a less technical audience.</h1>
                    <div id="view-project">
                        <a href="#">View Project</a>
                        <img src="Images/arrow-black.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img id="ipad" src="Images/ipad.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>


</body>

</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
@import url("http://fast.fonts.net/t/1.css?apiType=css&projectid=b4314e71-83d8-4cc4-bd90-9ceb4a5339d0");
@font-face{
    font-family:"Tisa W01 Light";
    src:url("Fonts/63d98d82-cdc2-4f22-8883-bede07823185.eot?#iefix");
    src:url("Fonts/63d98d82-cdc2-4f22-8883-bede07823185.eot?#iefix") format("eot"),url("Fonts/163f4b9f-d9b9-42c5-9098-d70e0016ae27.woff2") format("woff2"),url("Fonts/cc68d660-f674-409c-9be1-7f7f8bc0542a.woff") format("woff"),url("Fonts/2385d9d0-f23e-4d30-abb4-28817eda1254.ttf") format("truetype"),url("Fonts/a9d1c46b-d28d-4dab-8373-bbaf41232d7f.svg#a9d1c46b-d28d-4dab-8373-bbaf41232d7f") format("svg");
}
@font-face{
    font-family:"Tisa W01 Regular";
    src:url("Fonts/885a1883-0bbc-429a-91f5-c32e88a82b0e.eot?#iefix");
    src:url("Fonts/885a1883-0bbc-429a-91f5-c32e88a82b0e.eot?#iefix") format("eot"),url("Fonts/36a5385d-e6c3-4aba-ad04-fa161f5c96b0.woff2") format("woff2"),url("Fonts/9b2fef91-4d32-413d-864e-4aaa363673eb.woff") format("woff"),url("Fonts/131d9e79-a2a5-4e3a-8cb9-e8acfcaa1c8a.ttf") format("truetype"),url("Fonts/419b1ef5-3ea5-43d3-8c3f-f68edc3d0a2b.svg#419b1ef5-3ea5-43d3-8c3f-f68edc3d0a2b") format("svg");
}

@font-face{
    font-family:"Tisa W01 Medium";
    src:url("Fonts/7901ab62-60f6-49a3-9332-359efb61e81b.eot?#iefix");
    src:url("Fonts/7901ab62-60f6-49a3-9332-359efb61e81b.eot?#iefix") format("eot"),url("Fonts/785e7c0f-c445-4077-b412-1fd0a1a8ab06.woff2") format("woff2"),url("Fonts/7ee6ca7c-fe74-4640-a75d-939ea0bd637d.woff") format("woff"),url("Fonts/d76d30ec-b31a-4502-acf4-89812c16447e.ttf") format("truetype"),url("Fonts/9ce8adf1-e8ae-4095-84d3-6b2f836cd33e.svg#9ce8adf1-e8ae-4095-84d3-6b2f836cd33e") format("svg");
}

@font-face{
    font-family:"Tisa W01 Bold";
    src:url("Fonts/0b58340f-a8ca-4e68-8eab-bfda350b0b58.eot?#iefix");
    src:url("Fonts/0b58340f-a8ca-4e68-8eab-bfda350b0b58.eot?#iefix") format("eot"),url("Fonts/02a4b96f-e988-44fe-a0e7-57ff1b610f3b.woff2") format("woff2"),url("Fonts/78d1ac04-d453-4364-8326-035a105b0865.woff") format("woff"),url("Fonts/776e5c1b-6939-4b32-9c0d-2dee7c34c7da.ttf") format("truetype"),url("Fonts/edc51787-36cf-434d-a4f1-b04139da6bfc.svg#edc51787-36cf-434d-a4f1-b04139da6bfc") format("svg");
}




/* Global */

body, a {
    font-family:"Tisa W01 Light", serif;
    color: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

p {
    font-size: 19px; 
    line-height: 1.8;
}

h1{
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    margin: 0 0 40px 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h2{
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h3{
    font-family: "Tisa W01 Medium", serif;
    font-size: 26px;
    margin: -5px 0 40px 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container{
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#view-project{
    display: inline !important;
    opacity: .5 !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

#view-project a{
    font-family: "San Francisco", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#view-project img{
    width: 15px !important;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    float: none !important;
}



/* Intro Section */

#header-block{
    padding: 140px 50px 140px 50px;
}

#extra-info{
    margin-top: 40px !important;
    font-size: 18px;
    opacity: .4;
}

#extra-info p{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#extra-info a{
    font-family: "Tisa W01 Medium", serif;
}


/* Glofox Section */

#glofox-block{
    background-color: #2b4ea4;
    height: 800px;
}

#glofox-block #number{
    opacity: .2;
    font-family: "Tisa W01 Regular", serif;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#glofox-block img{
    z-index: 1;
    width: 740px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 60px;
}

#glofox-block .container #text{
    position: relative;
    top: -790px;
    z-index: 2;
    float: right;
    width: 350px;
    color: white;
    float: right;
}

#glofox-block #view-project a{
    color: white;
    border: none;
}


/* Webfaction Section */

#webfaction-block #ipad{
    z-index: 1;
    width: 795px;
    position: relative;
    top: -100px;
}

#webfaction-block h1{
    width: 750px;
}

#webfaction-block #text{
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Copy-and-pasting your code into a blank jsfiddle and then inspecting it, shows the same as what your screenshot already does - that the element adheres to the width you have specified with `#webfaction-block h1 { width: 750px; }` ... not sure what the actual question is here?

Comment: Are you just confused by how the inspector highlights the space to the right of the element in regard to the width of its containing block, and the bottom margin ...?

Comment: @CBroe I tried pasting the code in a JSFiddle and got the same problem: the H1 doesn't actually use the full 750px of width it has. At 750px the text should fit on two lines, not 3. Is this what you saw or am I missing something? https://www.dropbox.com/s/wqighksf0o6pd99/Screenshot%202018-07-15%2016.24.37.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Even the tooltip clearly shows the element as 750px wide... Your text flow issue must be due to something else.

Comment: @CBroe I assume it wasn't as simple as just the width being wrong, but what's preventing the text from taking up the full width of the H1?

Comment: Can you set up a full [mcve] somewhere?

Comment: Sure, here's the project (same code I attached above but also the images and fonts needed to render it correctly):  https://github.com/CristianMoisei/personal-website

Comment: I rather meant "live", in-action ...

Comment: I see: http://stage.hyperion.co/personal-website/

Comment: It's the floated `#text` element from the first block (#glofox-block) - that keeps space reserved that the _inline_ text content of your following headline floats around. Multiple issues with your code besides that - ids _have_ to be unique within a document, that numbering should rather not be done using separate h1 elements (go look up CSS counters), non-breaking spaces used to create what should be a margin or padding, the decorative slashes between the navigation links probably should be generated content than actual spans, ...

Comment: You're right the #text element is the issue. How else could I go about placing that element there? And thanks for the suggestions, I'm not really a programmer (I'm a designer learning to code) so any advice is welcome.

Comment: If you pull that mentioned #text container up not via relative positioning and `top: -790px;` but rather a `margin-top: -790px;` instead, it fixes a lot of the issue already, I think. Relative positioning always keeps the space the element would have occupied originally reserved, and only moves the rendered output in relation to that - that is what is keeps the following text at bay here mostly to begin with. If you use a negative margin-top however, you drag the whole element up "to begin with", so the influence on the following flow is quite different.

Comment: Thank you for helping me identify the issue @CBroe

Answer (score -1):

In order to fix this you need to add the following line to your CSS:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

Please familiarise yourself with CSS whitespace parameters.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Comment: Are you sure Aiden? nowrap would only cause the text to never wrap at all, which is not what I am trying to do, what I can't fix is getting it to fill the full width of its container. white-space: normal; doesn't help either.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, where did you add the white-space: nowrap; ?

Comment: Ops - my mistake. Add it to your H1 tag: #webfaction-block h1

Comment: I did try that and the results are this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xl1iawau1i1m7zc/Screenshot%202018-07-15%2016.42.44.jpg?dl=0